# final list re- assignment

Tags: java, list, collections

creating final list as

`final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();`

will not let me re-assign the list because list is final.

`list = new ArrayList<String>();`
will give compilation error.

but after insertion of 16th element , a new ArrayList must be created with capacity =oldCapacity *3/2 +1 and must be assigned to list.

how JVM allowing re-assignment of final list in this case.

Comment: yes ... that is what the final keyword does. if you want list to become a new ArrayList, don't declare it as final

Comment: but, why on earth would you want that? Lists are not like Arrays. When they are "full", and you add another element, their size automatically increases

Comment: Final does not mean immutable

Comment: @JeroenSteenbeeke for the *contents* of the object not to change, your object would have to be *deep* immutable and that is not what usually immutable is implemented like. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47527433/1059372

Comment: @Eugene very good explanation of the point I was trying to make

Comment: @JeroenSteenbeeke oh! I thought u mean something different... my bad

Answer (score 5):

> but after insertion of 16th element , a new ArrayList must be created with capacity =oldCapacity *3/2 +1 and must be assigned to list

No, a new backing array is created (when inserting the 11th element). The backing array is an instance variable of the `ArrayList` (defined as `transient Object[] elementData;`). The assignment is performed to that instance variable, which is not `final`.

A new `ArrayList` instance is not created, and the `list` variable still references the same instance.

Therefore there is no assignment to a final variable in the scenario you describe.

Answer (score 3):

No. ArrayList wont get replaced. Backed array gets expand, accordingly.

While adding element to the list, ArrayList make sure that it have enough capacity

```
public boolean add(E e) {
378         ensureCapacity(size + 1);  // Increments modCount!!
379         elementData[size++] = e;
380         return true;
381     }
```

Here is the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.ensureCapacity%28int%29) of ensuring capacity. If needed, it gets expand.

```
public void ensureCapacity(int minCapacity) {
179         modCount++;
180         int oldCapacity = elementData.length;
181         if (minCapacity > oldCapacity) {
182             Object oldData[] = elementData;
183             int newCapacity = (oldCapacity * 3)/2 + 1;
184             if (newCapacity < minCapacity)
185                 newCapacity = minCapacity;
186             // minCapacity is usually close to size, so this is a win:
187             elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, newCapacity);
188         }
189     }
```

And also if, list is `final`, you can't reassign it. However you can still add modify it's internal things through methods.

Answer (score 1):

`final references` don't change, the *internals* of the final objects can still change, unless they are *deep* immutable. Usually immutability means that the size of the collections can not be changed.

For example:

```
    List<StringBuilder> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new StringBuilder("can we?"));
    Collection<StringBuilder> canNotChange = Collections.unmodifiableCollection(list);

    StringBuilder sb = canNotChange.iterator().next();
    sb.setCharAt(0, '!');

    System.out.println(canNotChange); // !an we?
```

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList` contains an object `array` as its property. When the list "expands", it actually the `array` object expanding, hence the `array` is re-created (address change) but not the `ArrayList` itself.